# Let Users add their markers on Mapbox

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

Is there a way to let users add custom markers on [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com/) through a search field? Much like google maps when you add a address and it puts a pin on the place you searched, I want to let users add their places. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you're expecting the locations to be *stored*, or for it to be a geocoder, like Google Maps's basic geocoder. For the latter, look into the [MapBox geocoding example](http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geocoding/).